# How can I automatically extract data from a constantly updated Excel file with a download button on a website?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerbi, data-science, powerquery

I want to automatically receive updated excel data on a website. I tried it with Selenium but how can I do this with Power BI?

When I try it with Power BI, it detects the text as a button and does not download the excel file, it prints the title of the link to the table as text.

Would you suggest any automation that will click on the Excel image in the picture and display the data? It doesn't have to be Power BI.

Thank you
[Excel File Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f9qF.png)

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, Power BI's Get Data / From Web requires a URL that returns a file. Ideally you would find out what static link the button is using and provide that to Power BI.

If the link is dynamic, you could start the Power BI query with a python script that calls selenium to find the link, or download the file to a static location.

Comment: Can I use Selenium in the python script in Power Bi as I normally use it?

Comment: Do you normally use Selenium in python?

Comment: I can use Selenium, but how can I automatically download constantly updated excel files on a website?

Comment: You can start a new Query using Get Data / Python, returning a pandas dataframe. Then you can add more steps to the Query in the Power Query Editor if needed.  Here's the doco: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts